# Datatables - Tfoot form doesn't work when using scrollbar horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I have data and I want to show my data using datatables

I want to show the data in datatables using a horizontal scroll bar,
but I have a problem when I add the horizontal scroll bar.
Tfoot form for search be disabled

this is my table before using a horizontal scroll bar
[image]
you can see in bottom tfoot form is enabled

[image]

you can see in bottom tfoot form be disabled for only text

How do I enable tfoot form when I activate the horizontal scroll bar?

this is my code:

```js
var dTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    dTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "pages/proses/serverSide.php?type=kategori_sekolah",
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "scrollX": true,
        "columnDefs": [
        { "orderable": true,  "targets": 0, "searchable": true },
        { "orderable": true,  "targets": 1, "searchable": true },
        { "orderable": true,  "targets": 2, "searchable": true },
        { "orderable": true,  "targets": 3, "searchable": true },
        { "orderable": true,  "targets": 4, "searchable": true },
        { "orderable": false, "targets": 5, "searchable": false }
        ]
    } );

    $('#example').removeClass( 'display' ).addClass('table table-striped table-bordered');
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {


        if( $(this).text() != "Action" ){
            var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" class="form-control" />' );
        }
    } );


    dTable.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            that
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
        } );
    } );
} );
```

```html
<table id="example"width="100%">    
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Provinsi</th>
        <th>Kota/Kabupaten</th>
        <th>Kecamatan</th>
        <th>Jenjang</th>
        <th>Nama Sekolah</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
<tfoot>
        <th>Provinsi</th>
        <th>Kota/Kabupaten</th>
        <th>Kecamatan</th>
        <th>Jenjang</th>
        <th>Nama Sekolah</th>
        <th>Action</th>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Help me, Thank's